# How to shrink proguard deobfuscation file

Tags: android, proguard

i started to get an error in google play console and i am unable to upload an AAB after upgrading to AS Giraffe patch 2. i dont know if that is the issue but i have no idea how to change the size of the deobfuscation file

```
Your Android App Bundle contains a Proguard deobfuscation file that is too large (2191 MB). Maximum allowed size is1600 MB.
```

Comment: I would open the app bundle file in a ZIP tool. Based on it's size the Proguard file should not be difficult to find and then check it's content.

Comment: thanks, i took a long approach to it and removed a suspicious library. it ended up being TheoPlayer, once i removed it i freed up over 2gb of mappings. now its just 60mb but will need to create new proguard rules for it. the ones they have on the site are way out of date and dont work well